# How do I return a user to a partial Gravity Forms entry in Wordpress using the Partial Entry addon?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I purchased the Gravity Forms developer license and activated the Partial entry addon. It is saving the partial entries, but how can I get the user back to the form where they can edit and complete the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution! Use these plugins:

- Gravity Forms Partial Entries Addon
- Save and Continue Link Recovery for Gravity Forms
- Gravity Forms  Edit Entries

Use this code in your functions.php to change the number of days link will be active:

`add_filter( 'gform_incomplete_submissions_expiration_days','your_function_name', 10, 1 );`

```
function your_function_name( $expiration_days ) {$expiration_days = 90; return  $expiration_days;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After conversations with their support team, it was determined that this is not how the plugin is meant to work, and there is no solution without custom coding.